# Google Apps Script to copy range in spreadsheet using sheet reference (not sheet name)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy a range in a spreadsheet from one row to another - but the name of the sheet changes and I am unable to work out how to use the sheet reference rather than sheet name when referring to the range.

Example code below which works - however I need to tell GAS to go get the ***first sheet***, not ***sheet "S1"***

```
function copyRange() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ofua0Tzut5fnZRLkXwldy4pq4AVupdvNYybrFGrHjBU").getSheetByName("S1")
var source_range = sheet.getRange("A2:G2");
var target_range = sheet.getRange("A3:G3");
source_range.copyTo(target_range);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `Example code below which works - however I need to tell GAS to go get the first sheet, not sheet "S1"`, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ofua0Tzut5fnZRLkXwldy4pq4AVupdvNYybrFGrHjBU").getSheetByName("S1")
```

#### To:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ofua0Tzut5fnZRLkXwldy4pq4AVupdvNYybrFGrHjBU").getSheets()[0];
```

- By this modification, the 1st tab is used as `sheet`. When `[0]` of `getSheets()[0]` is changed to `[1]`, the 2nd sheets is used. When you changed the arangement of the sheet, the sheet is changed. For example, when you move the 1st tab from 3rd tab, `getSheets()[0]` retrieves the current 1st tab. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())